# cannot split email address and show on text box

Tags: excel, vba, email

I am selecting an email address from a combobox using a form in Excel and want to split the email address and display only first name from the selected email address. Please check the code as below:

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Me.CboBugSts.List = Array("Open-Crtical", "Open-ShowStopper")
    Me.CboCC.List = Array("Nandesh.kalyankar@wipro.com")
    Me.CboToEmail.List = Array("firstName.LastName@Email.com")
    Me.CboGrtngs.List = Array("Hi", "Dear")
    TxtSubj.Value = "Bug notification logged by " & Environ("Username") & " - " & Now

End Sub

Private Sub TxtMsg_Change()

    arTemp = Split(Me.CboToEmail.Text, "@")
    Fname = arTemp(LBound(arTemp))
    TxtMsg.Text = Me.CboGrtngs.Text & " " & Fname

End Sub
```

Here `Me.CboToEmail.text` is a value that user selects from a combobox text, and then I split the email address and concatenate it with another combobox text `Me.CboGrtngs.text`, but it shows the whole email, not just the first name from email.

Comment: I've tried to recreate the issue that you are facing, but it seems to be working to me - I created a userform with a combox then the code correctly creates an array of the text `Me.CboToEmail.text` with `@` as the delimiter, `Fname` then takes first element in the array as you'd expect. Could you give an example of `Me.CboToEmail.text` that isn't working? (I wonder if there is some discrepancy in `@` in combo box text and that specified in the `Split` function)

Comment: Thank you so very much for your insights Sam. Here is the code for your preview

    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        Me.CboBugSts.List = Array("Open-Crtical", "Open-ShowStopper")
    Me.CboCC.List = Array("Nandesh.kalyankar@wipro.com")
    Me.CboToEmail.List = Array("firstName.LastName@Email.com")
    Me.CboGrtngs.List = Array("Hi", "Dear")
    TxtSubj.Value = "Bug notification logged by " & Environ("Username") & " - " & Now
End Sub
Private Sub TxtMsg_Change()
arTemp = Split(Me.CboToEmail.text, "@")
Fname = arTemp(LBound(arTemp))
TxtMsg.text = Me.CboGrtngs.text & "  " & Fname
End Sub

Comment: Due to character limitations for edit, I am unable to format code. Apologizes for any inconvenience :)

Comment: that's ok, I updated your question with the full code. Unfortunately I've tested this updated code and again works fine for me. The only thing I can think of (as I mentioned before) is that in the real list of emails for `Me.CboToEmail.List` there aren't `@` signs present, so split can't separate them. If this isn't it hopefully one of the others here can work it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure (not a vba programmer), but since `CboToEmail` is defined as a list or array (with one item):

```
Me.CboToEmail.List = Array("firstName.LastName@Email.com")
```

Don't you need to extract the first element here, instead of calling .Text on the whole list?

```
arTemp = Split(Me.CboToEmail.Text, "@")
```

If not, what's the value of `Me.CboToEmail.Text`?